# MobaTextEditor: change background colour

Tags: mobaxterm

Since recently, I'm using MobaXterm version 23.5, Personal Edition on a Windows 10, Home Edition machine.  I'm also using MobaTextEditor as the default text editor.

Looks like the theme of MobaTextEditor is "hard connected" to the theme used by/chosen for MobaXterm itself.

Does this mean there's absolutely no way to, for instance, change the background colour of the text editor to a colour of my choice?  Or is there?